# Why are there multiple ajaxtoolkit libraries, 1 per language?

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I don't have much experience in making app multi lingual, but it seems to me that you don't need a separate dll for each language that you want to handle.

Could someone speculate why the toolkit was designed this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops. They aren't separate dlls, just separate resources. This makes more sense.